Restrict which networks a user is allowed to connect to
I'm setting up user accounts for the PCs of a computer lab, which run Ubuntu 24.04. I'd like the users to be able to connect only to our Wi-Fi network, forbidding access to other nearby networks, phone hotspots, etc. How can I do it?

Answer to your question is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189496/how-to-disable-network-access-for-a-user

@pbies Wait, that's about disabling network access altogether as far as I understand. I want to let the user access a network, only it must be the network of my choice.

You can do that with iptables.

@pbies Do you know how?

You have all the info in the link I shared.

@pbies What information people gather from the same source is subjective, isn't it? ;) I'll try anyway
